# Source a file after ssh login drops to prompt

Tags: bash, ssh, zsh, source

**One-liner question:** How do I automatically source a remote file on remote host after logging in via SSH via a bastion host?

I need to source a file containing a list of aliases + shell user defined functions on a remote host after ssh-ing into it.

The file exists on remote maching in /tmp folder e.g. /tmp/my-rc

Searching other posts and internet I have found

```
ssh -t user@domain.com 'source /tmp/my-rc; bash -l'
```

The problem is that I do get a terminal, but none of the aliases are set since it's a new bash shell'

Thinking, that the source should be done after the shell is attached, tried the below but this also doesn't work. There is no error, I get the terminal but don't think the file got sourced (verified by echoing dummy message from /tmp/my-rc file)

```
ssh -t user@domain.com 'bash -l; source /tmp/my-rc'
```

Even tried with '.' instead of source, no luck.

Any help.

Note1: Bash or ZSH any shell solution would do.

Note2: The actuall ssh is via a proxy command i.e. a hop over bastion host (Just mentioning if it is relevant at all)

Note3: I don't have privilage of a profile rc or bashrc or even a home directory on the remote host.

Note4: The exact command that I used to login into the secure host is via bastion host like below

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='ssh -W %h:%p ec2-3-218-12-120.compute-1.amazonaws.com' 10.0.31.122
```

Comment: To be completely sure: you can create files (and directories?) in `/tmp` on the remote host, but you don't have a `HOME` directory there. Both Bash and Zsh are installed on the remote host. Is it correct? What is the value of `HOME` when you start an interactive shell on the remote host via SSH?

Comment: @fra-san value of $HOME is  `/home/tareque`, but there is no such directory. When I enter just `cd`, which should take me to home dir, I get message  `cd: no such file or directory: /home/tareque`

Comment: @fra-san Yes I am able to create directories and files in `/tmp`. Bash and Zsh are installed on remote host already.

Comment: Similar: [Login by ssh , exec one command and i don't want to quit the bash](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/152173)

Comment: Or [Sourcing bashrc file fails with ssh -t](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/152499)

Comment: For zsh, see [Start zsh with a custom zshrc](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/131716)

Answer (score 4):

With `bash`, you can do:

```
ssh -t user@host '
  PROMPT_COMMAND="source /tmp/my-rc
                  unset PROMPT_COMMAND
                 " exec bash --norc'
```

Which would cause `/tmp/my-rc` to be sourced before the prompt, and only that prompt since we unset `PROMPT_COMMAND` afterwards.

You'll want to remove the `unset PROMPT_COMMAND` if `/tmp/my-rc` actually ends up defining it.

The above assumes the login shell of the remote user is Bourne-like, but you should be able to adapt it to most other types of shells (csh / rc / fish).

Comment: Thanks. This solution also works.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you can write to the remote host's `/tmp`, you can create a `/tmp/myhome` directory on it, put your shells' profile and initialization files there and then start Zsh with `ZDOTIDR` set to `/tmp/myhome` and Bash with `HOME` set to `/tmp/myhome`.

By default, Zsh searches for its initialization files in `$ZDOTDIR`, defaulting to `$HOME` if `ZDOTDIR` is not set.

Hence, you can start Zsh on the remote host as:

```
ssh -t user@host ZDOTDIR=/tmp/myhome zsh
```

And Bash as:

```
ssh -t user@host HOME=/tmp/myhome bash
```

Of course you can be creative with your profile/initialization files—e.g. use them to set `HOME` to a more suitable path, source other files (if you happened to already have dot-files somewhere on the remote host), etc.

A minimal application of this approach, condensed in one command, could be:

```
ssh -t user@host 'mkdir /tmp/myhome
  echo ". /tmp/my-rc" >/tmp/myhome/.bashrc
  HOME=/tmp/myhome bash'
```

(Use `mkdir -p ...` to prevent an error from being shown when `/tmp/myhome` already exists, e.g. if you are reconnecting to the remote host and you already know the directory is there).

Taking your `ProxyCommand` into account, it could be:

```
ssh -t -o ProxyCommand='ssh -W \
  %h:%p ec2-3-218-12-120.compute-1.amazonaws.com' \
  10.0.31.122 \
  'mkdir /tmp/myhome
  echo ". /tmp/my-rc" >/tmp/myhome/.bashrc
  HOME=/tmp/myhome bash'
```

Finally, about your attempts: `ssh -t user@domain.com 'bash -l; source /tmp/my-rc'` is not working because the `source` command is only executed after the interactive shell exits.

Comment: I have added the exact ssh command that I use to login via a bastion host... Your solution doesn't seem to work. Tried adding the HOME/ZDOTDIR to the ProxyCommand as well as to the outer ssh command.

Comment: To make sure we are on the same page, I added a complete command based on your edited question. Please, add some information on _how_ it doesn't work for you, if it is the case (e.g. does it show any error messages? Does it hang?).

Comment: Appreciate the effort.. Tried the updated proxyCommand, the terminal just hangs with output `Could not chdir to home directory /home/tareque` .. I have created `/tmp/.mtk` with `.bashrc .profile `The command I used

`ssh -o ProxyCommand='ssh -W %h:%p ec2-3-218-12-120.compute-1.amazonaws.com  ' 10.0.31.122 'HOME=/tmp/.mtk bash'`

Comment: You are forgetting the `-t` option, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks :) bash solution tried, tested and worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If *UsePAM* is set to *yes* in the remote hosts's sshd_config file, then config file **/etc/pam.d/sshd** allows you to automize command execution upon successful login, among other events in the authentication process. Add this line of code

```
session    required     pam_exec.so /etc/myscripts/./sourcing-script
```

directly above these lines

```
# SELinux needs to intervene at login time to ensure that the process starts
# in the proper default security context.  Only sessions which are intended
# to run in the user's context should be run after this.
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so open
```

where /etc/myscripts/sourcing-script simply is a file on the remote host with the command to execute upon successful login.

```
#!/bin/bash
source /tmp/my-rc
#echo $(date) >> /etc/myscripts/sourcing-script.log
#cat /tmp/my-rc >> /etc/myscripts/sourcing-script.log
```

I use this method to stop a service and report it to a log file, before my ssh session is opened. Before I log out I set a crontab to start the service, so it never runs parallel with my ssh session.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you do this in `$HOME/.profile` or variants.

`ssh` sets environments variables starting with `SSH_`, you can use those to determine if you logged in via `ssh`, or directly.

Comment: I don't have a home directory setup on remote host.. Have added this info to the question. Yes I understand this is a key point, i missed to say. Sorry. Without home directory, profile rc/bashrc is there a way to achieve my ask?